# Issue on Pushing HTML Element into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/tmma57um/)**

I need to pass a checkbox element markup into an array. I am using this code

```
  var counter = 0;
  var compareTable = [];
  var compareRow = [];

  var check = $("<input  value='" + counter + "' name='case[]' id='selbox" + counter + "' type='checkbox'><label for=" + "selbox" + counter + "><span></span></label>");

  compareRow.push(check);
  console.log(compareRow);
  alert(compareRow[0]);
```

but am getting [object object] as the result. Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please let me know why did you vote down this question?

Comment: Alert is calling `.toString()` on your object, that's expected.  Check your console.

Comment: And why would you need to put a jQuery object inside an array, there's generally no reason to do so ?

Comment: I need to create a dynamic Data table so I have to pass checkbox there too

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push HTML in to an array this is not the approach:

```
var check = $("<input  value='" + counter + "' name='case[]' id='selbox" + counter + "' type='checkbox'><label for=" + "selbox" + counter + "><span></span></label>");
```

but this:

```
var check = "<input  value='" + counter + "' name='case[]' id='selbox" + counter + "' type='checkbox'><label for=" + "selbox" + counter + "><span></span></label>";
```

I updated your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hz2qc61q/) Check it.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var check = $("<input  value='" + counter ...
```

will create a special jQuery object. If you want to get the HTML element itself - simply call `get(0)`.

This will alert `[Object HTMLInputElement]`:

```
alert(compareRow[0].get(0));
```

But if later you'll need to append the created elements to another node - there's no need to get anything. E.g. jQuery `append` method can accept several kinds of arguments. Among them `jQuery object` ([read more](http://api.jquery.com/append/)).

**Note:** you create 2 DOM elements (input and label). To get the 2nd one (label) - call `get(1)`